# Parsing a messy json inside a dataframe column

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**

Let´s say i've a got a pyspark dataframe, one of its columns is a messy json (not in standard form, single level but with double quotes and #)

```
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|DeskIndex|            MetaData|    ContentMediaType|
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    False|"{""#stateName"":...|          text/plain|
|    False|"{""#stateName"":...|          text/plain|
|    False|"{""channel"":""C...|          text/plain|
|    False|"{""channel"":""C...|          text/plain|
|    False|"{""#stateName"":...|          text/plain|
|    False|"{""#stateName"":...|          text/plain|
|    False|"{""#stateName"":...|application/qnd.l...|
|    False|"{""#stateName"":...|          text/plain|
|    False|"{""#stateName"":...|          text/plain|
|    False|"{""#blip.payload...|          text/plain|
|    False|"{""#stateName"":...|          text/plain|
|    False|"{""channel"":""C...|          text/plain|
|    False|"{""#stateName"":...|          text/plain|
|    False|"{""#blip.payload...|          text/plain|
|    False|"{""#blip.payload...|          text/plain|
|    False|"{""#stateName"":...|application/qnd.l...|
|    False|"{""#stateName"":...|application/qnd.l...|
|    False|"{""channel"":""C...|          text/plain|
|    False|"{""#stateName"":...|application/qnd.l...|
|    False|"{""#stateName"":...|application/qnd.l...|
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Example of row in metadata column:

```
 "{""#stateName"":""[K.9.2.3]bar"",""#stateId"":""thebar"",""#messageId"":""data:43ff-89e6-62aa235df798"",""#previousStateId"":""80b7-4a5978a03a47"",""#previousStateName"":""[K.9.2.2]foo "",""trace-id"":""84499a247d3%3A1"",""#uniqueId"":""42-9625-58da4a2cbd1f"",""date_created"":""2227"",""#tunnel.originalFrom"":""host-7"",""#tunnel.originalTo"":""1b16@mail.net"",""$originator"":""provider@mail.net"",""$claims"":""Node=provider@mail.net/i-hosted7Identity=provider@mail.netDomainRole=MemberScheme=Transport"",""$internalId"":""58da4a2cbd1f""}"
```

Is there a way to break this json data in multiple columns?

**WHAT I`VE TRIED SO FAR**

1 - Most solutions i´ve found require me to declare a schema. But since i don´t the order of the data in each json, how should i work it out?

2- According to solution here,
[PySpark: Read nested JSON from a String Type Column and create columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63502556/pyspark-read-nested-json-from-a-string-type-column-and-create-columns),

under the following code i was able to separate, but all columns returned null

```
df0 = df1.select(F.get_json_object(F.col('MetaData'), "$.#stateName").alias("State Name"),
          F.get_json_object(F.col('MetaData'), "$.#stateId").alias("State ID"),
          F.get_json_object(F.col('MetaData'), "$.#messageId").alias("Message Id"),
          F.get_json_object(F.col('MetaData'), "$.#previousStateId").alias("previousStateId"),
          F.get_json_object(F.col('MetaData'), "$.#previousStateName").alias("previousStateName"))
```

```
df0.show()
+----------+--------+----------+---------------+-----------------+
|State Name|State ID|Message Id|previousStateId|previousStateName|
+----------+--------+----------+---------------+-----------------+
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
|      null|    null|      null|           null|             null|
+----------+--------+----------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: If you can manage to remove the double quoutes `"` from the `json` elements then it is fairly simple to parse. You essentially need to use `from_json` and with `MapType` you can define the `key-value` pairs, which you can later `explode` to get individual columns per your use case.